# Rails 5: retrieve multiple objects through polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to retrieve multiple objects preferably in single query through polymorphic relationship.

In **User model** I have this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies, through: :accounts
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :medias, class_name: 'Media::Medias', through: :permissions,
           source: :permitable, source_type: 'Media::Medias'
end
```

then my **Permission model** looks like this:

```
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

**Media::Medias model**:

```
module Media
  class Medias < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :companies, optional: true, inverse_of: :medias
    has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission', as: :permitable
    has_many :users, through: :permissions
  end
end
```

**Company model**:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :accounts
  has_many :medias, class_name: 'Media::Medias', inverse_of: :company
end
```

**How do I return an `ActiveRecord::Relation object` for all medias for `current_user` and companies for each media?** It is important, I have to use relationship through `Permission` model, I should not get companies through `Accounts`. So far I've set up model so I can use `Current.user.medias` to get all medias for `current_user`.

Thank you!

**Update**

Here is what I got from several versions I tried:

```
[4] pry(main)> user.medias.includes(:companies).map{|media| media.companies.id }
  Media::Medias Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "media_medias".* FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
NameError: uninitialized constant Media::Medias::Companies
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:166:in `compute_type'
[5] pry(main)> user.medias.preload(:companies).select(['medias.id', 'medias.company.id'])
  Media::Medias Load (1.3ms)  SELECT medias.id, medias.company.id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
=> #<Media::Medias::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x33dd094>
[6] pry(main)> user.medias.select(['medias.id', 'medias.company_id'])
  Media::Medias Load (1.1ms)  SELECT medias.id, medias.company_id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
=> #<Media::Medias::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x3413234>
```

**Update 2**

```
[4] pry(main)> puts user.medias.preload(:companies).select(['medias.id', 'medias.company.id'])
  Media::Medias Load (1.4ms)  SELECT medias.id, medias.company.id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "medias"
LINE 1: SELECT medias.id, medias.company.id FROM "media_medias" INNE...
               ^
: SELECT medias.id, medias.company.id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:620:in `async_exec'
[5] pry(main)> puts user.medias.select(['medias.id', 'medias.company_id'])
  Media::Medias Load (1.2ms)  SELECT medias.id, medias.company_id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "medias"
LINE 1: SELECT medias.id, medias.company_id FROM "media_medias" INNE...
               ^
: SELECT medias.id, medias.company_id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2
from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:620:in `async_exec'
```

**Update 3**

```
[1] pry(main)> User.find(2).medias.preload(:companies).select(['medias.id', 'medias.company.id'])
  User Load (21.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Media::Medias Load (1.7ms)  SELECT medias.id, medias.company.id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
=> #<Media::Medias::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x17688f0>
[2] pry(main)> User.find(2).medias.select(['medias.id', 'medias.company_id'])
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Media::Medias Load (1.8ms)  SELECT medias.id, medias.company_id FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
=> #<Media::Medias::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x2155d90>
```

Comment: What do you get for `current_user.medias.includes(:companies)`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I see this in console: `[2] pry(main)> user.medias.includes(:companies)
  Media::Medias Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "media_medias".* FROM "media_medias" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "media_medias"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = $1 AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = $2  [["user_id", 2], ["permitable_type", "Media::Medias"]]
=> #<Media::Medias::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0xce32a4>`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon It does not look it gives me desired result + I need to get back both - medias and companies.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'get back both'? You can have only one object preloaded with associated objects. Can you write your query in sql?

Comment: As i can see in the query, it doesn't load `company`. Try `preload` instead of `includes`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon `preload` does not help. I need to [get raw records for ajax-datatables-rails](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails#get-raw-records) and I need records from two models - `Media::Medias` and `Company`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon OK, `user.medias.preload(:companies).ids` gives back me ids of `Media::Medias`. How do I get `Companies` for each `Media::Medias` please?

Comment: What happens if you do: `user.medias.includes(:companies).map{|media| media.company.id }`?

Comment: @marksiemers I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Media::Medias::Companies`  In my `media_medias` table I have column `company_id`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your associations close enough: `user.medias.includes(:companies).map{|media| media.companies.id }`. Although, you may want to change your association name to `belongs_to :company, ...` in your `Medias` class.

Comment: And what do you get for `user.medias.preload(:companies).select(['medias.id', 'medias.company.id'])` and `user.medias.select(['medias.id', 'medias.company_id'])`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon please, see above in update - did not get any records back

Comment: That's strange..replace `puts` with `p`..if that throws an error too, try `query.inspect`.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon `p` gives same thing

Comment: Can you do that in irb console instead of debugger. U won't need puts there. Run the query for the same user like `User.find(2).medias...`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Please, see in Update 3 above what I see in my console (pry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this out of comments, it looks like the issue (or at least a large issue) is the confusion of plural/singular elements in model names and associations.  In general:

1. Model names are singular.  In this case, "medium" is the singular and "media" is the plural.
2. When using the association constructs in models, a "has_many" will typically take a plural whereas a "belongs_to" will take a singular.  So, expect `has_many :companies` and `belongs_to :user`.
3. The underlying table names are plural. So, the "Medium" model is based on the "media" table.

With that out of the way, I created a simple Rails app which serves as a minimal working example of the above code.  Since the "Account" model doesn't appear here I removed the corresponding elements from the Company model.  I also added inverse associations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permissions, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :media, class_name: 'Medium::Medium', through: :permissions, source: :permitable, source_type: 'Medium::Medium'
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :media, class_name: 'Medium::Medium', inverse_of: :company
end

class Medium::Medium < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, optional: true, inverse_of: :media
  has_many :permissions, class_name: 'Permission', as: :permitable, inverse_of: :permitable
  has_many :users, through: :permissions
end

class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :permitable, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :permissions
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :permissions
end
```

Sample console session with test data:

```
2.2.7 :001 > Company.create(name: 'IBM')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "IBM"], ["created_at", "2017-05-05 19:11:49.017155"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-05 19:11:49.017155"]]
   (0.5ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Company id: 1, name: "IBM", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:49", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:49"> 
2.2.7 :002 > User.create(name: 'Joe')
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Joe"], ["created_at", "2017-05-05 19:11:59.401417"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-05 19:11:59.401417"]]
   (2.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Joe", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:59", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:59"> 
2.2.7 :003 > Medium::Medium.create(name: 'TV')
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "medium_media" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "TV"], ["created_at", "2017-05-05 19:12:11.453440"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-05 19:12:11.453440"]]
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Medium::Medium id: 1, company_id: nil, name: "TV", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:11", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:11"> 
2.2.7 :004 > Medium::Medium.create(name: 'Newspaper')
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "medium_media" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Newspaper"], ["created_at", "2017-05-05 19:12:18.433671"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-05 19:12:18.433671"]]
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Medium::Medium id: 2, company_id: nil, name: "Newspaper", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:18", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:18"> 
2.2.7 :005 > user = User.first
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Joe", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:59", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:59"> 
2.2.7 :006 > user.permissions.create(permitable: Medium::Medium.first)
  Medium::Medium Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "medium_media".* FROM "medium_media" ORDER BY "medium_media"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "permissions" ("permitable_type", "permitable_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["permitable_type", "Medium::Medium"], ["permitable_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-05-05 19:12:50.694383"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-05 19:12:50.694383"]]
   (0.5ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Permission id: 1, permitable_type: "Medium::Medium", permitable_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:50", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:50"> 
2.2.7 :007 > user = User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Joe", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:59", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:11:59"> 
2.2.7 :008 > user.media
  Medium::Medium Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "medium_media".* FROM "medium_media" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "medium_media"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = ? AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["permitable_type", "Medium::Medium"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Medium::Medium id: 1, company_id: nil, name: "TV", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:11", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:11">]> 
2.2.7 :009 > user.media.includes(:company)
  Medium::Medium Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "medium_media".* FROM "medium_media" INNER JOIN "permissions" ON "medium_media"."id" = "permissions"."permitable_id" WHERE "permissions"."user_id" = ? AND "permissions"."permitable_type" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["permitable_type", "Medium::Medium"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Medium::Medium id: 1, company_id: nil, name: "TV", created_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:11", updated_at: "2017-05-05 19:12:11">]>
```

Just make sure to get your model names correct and it should work.  Sample code may be downloaded here:

https://github.com/mdchaney/so_43765182

Comment: Thank you, this helps! I revised my models, tables, columns according to your suggestion & [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions). It works just fine and looks nice :) Rails community the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an association on your User class:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :companies, through: :accounts
  has_many :permissions
  has_many :medias, class_name: 'Media::Medias', through: :permissions,
       source: :permitable, source_type: 'Media::Medias'
  has_many :media_companies, through: :medias, source: :companies
end
```

Then you should be able to do:
`User.find(2).media_companies`

Since you have a `belongs_to` association from media to company then you should consider using the singular `belongs_to :company` in your `Media::Medias` class.

If you do that, then you would amend the association in the `User` class to be:

```
has_many :media_companies, through: :medias, source: :company
```

If you want to keep it plural, then you will need to add an association option to get it to work (to avoid the `NameError: uninitialized constant Media::Medias::Companies` error):

```
module Media
  class Medias < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :companies, class_name: :Company, optional: true, inverse_of: :medias
    ...
  end
end
```

It would be more conventional to just switch it to singular though:

```
belongs_to :company, optional: true, inverse_of: :medias
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed: 1) `companies` to `company` and 2) `Media::Medias` to `Medium::Media` as @MichaelChaney suggested. I get back Companies now. How do I get Media for User as well, please?

Comment: I got it - `User.find(2).media.includes(:company)` now works just fine :)